# Where are templates for Metro Style Apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, visual-studio-2012

I downloaded and installed `WindowsDeveloperPreview-64bit-English-Developer.iso` on VMWare. But when I start `Visual Studio Express 11` which comes with `Windows 8` I cannot see any Windows Metro Style template. Why? Am I missing something?

As mentioned in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx) article I was expecting these templates

[image]

I can only see these templates

[image]

As mentioned by Iain I can see these templates in the directory he mentioned but how can I get them into VS?

[image]

Comment: The image yoyu are showing is from VS 2010. VS 2011 doesn't have a version selection.  You must have installed VS 2010 on that machine.  Go to the start menu and just start typing "Visual Studio" too see what you have installed.

Comment: It is Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did one registry change when I installed Windows 8
I changed value of `RPEnabled` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer` from `1` to `0` in order to get the normal Start menu

That was causing the issue I reverted the registry change and I can see the templates.

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/9ac3eb78-f4cf-4d01-901e-6f13e34bdad7) for details

Answer (score 0):

You could try this folder:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates.

You may find that the templates are zipped up in some form, but i do not have VS11 installed yet.

Within the zip file there is .vstemplate file you will need to modify the templateid and any other relevant information.

Cheers

Comment: You are right I have 5 templates in zip format in the directory you mentioned but how can I get them in to Visual Studio?

Comment: I think you add a new zip with a manifest. restart vs it should be there